# Ignore a certain part of the URL via mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Silex application and I get requests like this:
https://.../dev/foo/bar and want to rewrite them to https://.../index.php/foo/bar

Wheras "..." can be anything from "www.asd.com" to "localhost/~asd/folder".

My .htaccess file is located at the web root, https://.../

This is the normal mod_rewrite setup I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

My naive try by setting the RewriteBase failed:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /dev
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

There I get the error

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /dev/index.php on this server.
```

Also just rewriting failed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^dev/(.*) index.php [L]
```

Strangely, it doesn't just skip the dev part, but it tries to access /dev/foo/bar instead of the desired /foo/bar.

Any clue?

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: Hi, I added it to the question.

Comment: Perhaps change it to `RewriteRule ^dev/(.+)/? index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]` and use `$_GET['url']` to access the requested path.

Comment: Try adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` at top of your first .htaccess

Comment: How does the directory structure look like? Do you have `/path/to/dev/foo/bar`, or something else?

Comment: Hi, can be both. On the local system where I play around with it, I have /path/to/dev/foo/bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for me by combining mod_alias and mod_rewrite like this, `RewriteBase` works now:

```
Alias /dev /app/web
<Directory /app/web>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /dev
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</Directory>
```